# How to make inner table align with outer table

Tags: html, html-table

Here is my table:
http://jsfiddle.net/1uw1xsxr/

```
<table border=1 width=100%><tr><td>id</td><td>status</td><td>action</td><td>date</td><td>by</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=5><table border=1 width=100%>
    <tr><td>1257</td><td>red</td><td>go</td><td>1-1-2011</td><td>dora</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1257</td><td>red</td><td>go</td><td>1-1-2011</td><td>dora</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1257</td><td>red</td><td>go</td><td>1-1-2011</td><td>dora</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td></tr></table>
```

What I have to do so the inner table column aligns with outer table column?

Answer (score 2):

Set the same width of td on both tables:

```
table td {width: 20%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are those "outer table columns" your table headers?

If so, use:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Header1</th><th>Header2</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```